# looping 6 times, but only adding 3 records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, simple-html-dom

i'm scraping data using the simple html dom. However there seem to be some weird behaviour. it only add 3 records even though it writes test 6 times. How come it is looping 6 times and only adding 3 rows?

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://www.dailydot.com/tags/counter-strike/");

foreach($html->find("//li[@class='span4']") as $element) {
    echo "test";
    $title = strip_tags($element->find("//a[@class='article-title']/h3", 0));
    $img = $element->find("//div[@class='picfx']/a/img[@class='lzy-ld']", 0)->getAttribute('data-original');
    $link = $element->find("//a[@class='article-title']", 0)->href;
    $date = $element->find("//p[@class='byline']/time", 0)->datetime;
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO news (`title`, `url`, `image_url`, `news_text`, `referer_img`) VALUES ('$title', '$link', '$img', '$full_text_strip', 'test')");
}
```

Comment: You might want to var_dump($html->find("//li[@class='span4']")) before the loop to confirm that it is, in fact, looping over 6 elements. Additionally, you might want to check for any mysqli errors.  Also, your queries aren't safe. You need to escape your variables correctly.

Comment: Thank you! would appreciate if you made an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it fails 3 times :D thoses insert aren't injection safe. You should use [real escape string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). If you don't your code will fail if any of your variables contains a simple quote. (And it allow a bad guy to inject sql commands)

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://www.dailydot.com/tags/counter-strike/");

foreach($html->find("//li[@class='span4']") as $element) {


$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($element->find("//a[@class='article-title']/h3", 0)));
$img = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $element->find("//div[@class='picfx']/a/img[@class='lzy-ld']", 0)->getAttribute('data-original'));
$link = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $element->find("//a[@class='article-title']", 0)->href);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $element->find("//p[@class='byline']/time", 0)->datetime);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO news (`title`, `url`, `image_url`, `news_text`, `referer_img`) VALUES ('$title', '$link', '$img', '$full_text_strip', 'test')");
  echo "test ".mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Comment: Edit: Added mysqli_real_escape_string and showing the last sql error. (if any)

Comment: it cant find the variables with mysqli_real_escape_string? nothing comes out when i echo them

Comment: Edit: added $con parameter. If you really want to do this in the proper way you should take a look at parametized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
I hope the corrected code will run. It's hard to write code without the possibility to run it.

Comment: Yes i know i think i found the error regarding why it only add 3 records but run 6 times. I get following error on 3 of the loops

(You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

 Could it be because some of the variables include a ' character?